# How to align a speech bubble with an image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to align a speech bubble with an image so that it looks as if the character is trying to say something.

I understand that it won't be perfect but I would like it to be fluid and not absolute so that it looks kind of same on big screen monitors and laptop monitors as well.

I've added `margin-left: 205px;` but that doesn't seem to cut it..

example: http://jsfiddle.net/fUway/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better off setting the speech bubble to `display: relative;` and controlling the `top` and `left` properties to position the bubble exactly where you want it on the image:

```
<blockquote class="oval-thought" style="position: relative; top: 250px; left: 150px;"><p>yay</p></blockquote>
<img src="http://th00.deviantart.net/fs70/PRE/f/2010/310/7/4/super_sonic_sa2_by_mephilez-d329bcu.png" height="600" width="400"/>
```